# Целесообразность хранения 1000 записей по ключам id в качестве свойств объекта

Tags: node.js, структуры-данных

Друзья, встал вопрос о хранении списка активных пользователей, используя объект в качестве хеш-таблицы. Ключами (названиями свойств объекта) будут id пользователей, а значениями - ссылки на объекты с информацией.

Применяться это будет во внутреннем корпоративном чате - не думаю, что одновременно онлайн будет более 1000 человек. Скорее всего, даже до 300 не дотянет, но будем ориентироваться на 1000.

Так вот: насколько целесообразно хранить так информацию? Желательна линейная сложность как для хеш-таблиц. Я с ходу не нашел никаких статей на эту тему. Но насколько подсказывает здравый смысл, если объекты являются настоящими хеш таблицами, то под ними должны быть массивы, которые раздуются при 1000 пользователях многократно. Не хотелось бы загружать пакет с какими-нить деревьями... Хотя, логарифм тоже подойдет в моём случае.

**Буду рад ссылкам на тему мапок и любым советам.**

**UPD1:** Структура будет хранить данные пользователя вместе с сокетным подключением. Использоваться будет данная информация при проверке доступа ко всем действиям, но здесь задержки не будет, т.к. из сокета можно получить доступ к данным пользователя по ссылке. Поиск по ID нужен в двух укрупненных случаях: (1) При восстановлении или создании подключения - в момент аутентификации нужно проверить, имеется ли уже в структуре такой пользователь, чтобы не создавать лишний объект. (2) при приглашении или удалении пользователя из/в беседы/ду - нужно проверить есть ли добавляемый пользователь онлайн, чтобы выслать информацию сразу.

Comment: похоже на преждевременную оптимизацию

Comment: Действительно, я довольно мнителен в таких вопросах. Но так или иначе, в этом надо разобраться. Лучше сейчас по горячим следам тему разворошить, чем потом столкнуться и понять, что в нужный момент не прощупал дно.

Comment: тогда Вы не предоставляете нам необходимой информации о характере и частоте использования этой структуры данных

Comment: Резонное замечание - спасибо. Добавил UPD1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте так, у меня нет информации по линейной сложности, и не уверен, что у кого-то она будет. Но!

Мы можем открыть консоль в Google Chrome и создать объект:

```js
const o = {}

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    o[i] = {
        field1: `field1_${i}`,
        field2: `field2_${i}`,
        field3: `field3_${i}`,
        field4: `field4_${i}`,
        field5: `field5_${i}`,
    }
}
```

Мне не совсем понятна ваша формулировка о том, что значениями объекта будут ссылки на объекты с информацией. Не понятна в том смысле, что объекты в js - это итак референсные типы, то есть если вы храните не примитивы, то там в любом случае будут ссылки.
Созданный мной объект, тоже хранит ссылки на объекты с информацией о пользователях. Я не стал имитировать здесь хранение ссылки на сокет-подключение, вы можете, используя написанное далее, самостоятельно провести тестирование и получить реальные значения для ваших структур.

Итак, если после создания такого объекта сделать heap snapshot (там же в консоли, вкладка "Memory"), то можно увидеть, сколько данный объект занимает памяти. Приведу вам значения (скриншот делать не буду, мои данные легко проверить):

- Shallow Size: 56 - собственно, сколько памяти в байтах выделено под сам объект
- Retained Size: 235 160 - это количество памяти в байтах выделенное под объект, все ссылки на него и т.д.

Оба значения, как вы можете заметить, не особо велики.
Это вам ответ на переживания по поводу того, что что-то может "раздуться при 1000 пользователях многократно". Не раздуется.

Теперь что касается линейной сложности. Вам не нужна эта информация по одной причине: это js, любой "пакет с деревьями" будет основан на тех же структурах данных, а значит никакого выигрыша в производительности вы не получите, увы.

Кстати, что касается других типов/структур, можно обратить внимание на `Map`:

```js
const m = new Map()

for (let i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    m.set(i, {
        field1: `field1_${i}`,
        field2: `field2_${i}`,
        field3: `field3_${i}`,
        field4: `field4_${i}`,
        field5: `field5_${i}`,
    })
}
```

Созданный таким образом `Map` имеет такие показатели в heap snapshot:

- Shallow Size: 32
- Retained Size: 252 384

Разница в использовании памяти, как видите, незначительная, однако `Map` может быть удобней, если требуется итерироваться, получать актуальное количество записей, и вообще считается, что `Map` производительней, если у вас будут часто происходить операции добавления/удаления. Фактические и предполагаемые преимущества `Map` перед `Object` можно посмотреть [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%B8_Map).

В любом случае знайте, 1000 элементов - это крайне мало для того, чтобы всерьёз переживать. Храните, никаких проблем с производительностью вам это не принесёт.

Удачи!

Comment: Хороший ответ. Маленький уточняющий вопрос из разряда научного интереса скорее всего. Я могу добавить в object свойство с "любым" именем (читай ключом). И таких свойств может быть очень много. Вопрос вот, в чём: когда я обращаюсь к одному свойству из многих тысяч, то каким механизмом js ищет соответствие моего запрашиваемого имени свойства в огромном объекте? Перебирает все, хеш получает, дерево у него там за ширмой или что? :-) Ответ по теме я получил - на данный комментарий можно не отвечать... Но если знаете - будет интересно разобраться.

Comment: @Lex я когда-то интересовался этим вопросом (тоже просто академический интерес), и не нашёл в спецификациях никакой информации о том, как должны быть устроены объекты. Думаю, что логично было бы отдать это на откуп разработчикам js-движков, потому как объекты, кроме всего прочего имеют цепочку прототипов и всё вот это вот. Не уверен, что разработчики спецификаций стали бы продумывать детали реализации)